# Preview custom fonts in Android Studio

Tags: android, custom-font

Currently I'm using the pixlui library to use custom fonts, and it's great!
https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI

Is there any way to preview the custom fonts in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Library called **Smart Fonts** for Android. It allows you to **preview the custom fonts in the Layout Editor** of Android Studio.

The fonts are cached in memory so that they are loaded once.

Smart Fonts is easy to integrate with gradle, it is documented and available on GitHub:

https://github.com/smart-fun/SmartFonts

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. The way that PixelUI is setting the font doesn't work in the previewer.

They are only setting font in one constructor as is visible here:
https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI/blob/master/Library/src/com/neopixl/pixlui/components/textview/TextView.java

The constructor the editor is using is the second one, and the font is not set when the TextView is constructed this way.

Comment: If it was set in the other constructor, would it work?